# Calculate value using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with my invoice.

In one invoice I can add more products. Products are in 5 category, each category have a default price. For Example

```
Product 1 : TV, default price 350 $
Product 2 : Books, default price 50 $
....... 
Product 5 : Phone, default price 150 $
```

When I submit a invoice, I want to calculate and a total price, for example:

```
1. TV 1 * 350$ = 350$
2. Angular Book 1 * 50$ = 50$
    ....
5. Samsung Phone 2 * 150$ = 300$
```

For solution this, I write this code:

Component ts.

```
  onAddProduct() {
    let products = [];
    let newProduct = this.addProductForm.value  
    newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte1.default_price1 * this.p_Quantity;
    newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte4.default_price4 * this.p_Quantity;
    newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte2.default_price2 * this.p_Quantity;
    newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte3.default_price3 * this.p_Quantity;
    newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte5.default_price5 * this.p_Quantity;
    let prod = new Products(newProduct)
    this.product = newProduct;
    this.ps.addProduct(this.product);
    this.router.navigate(['/invoice']);
  }
```

In this code the problem is, in view the value in all time: `p_Quantity *  default_price` but in console show correct value.

Can you suggest any idea how to solution?

**Solution**

```
 onAddProduct() {
    let products = [];
    let newProduct = this.addProductForm.value
    if (this.addProductForm.controls.p_Product_type_id.value === '2') {
      newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte2.default_price2 * this.p_Quantity;
      let prod2 = new Products(newProduct);
    } else if (this.addProductForm.controls.p_Product_type_id.value === '1') {
      newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte1.default_price1 * this.p_Quantity;
      let prod1 = new Products(newProduct);
    } else if (this.addProductForm.controls.p_Product_type_id.value === '3') {
      newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte3.default_price3 * this.p_Quantity;
      let prod3 = new Products(newProduct);
    } else if (this.addProductForm.controls.p_Product_type_id.value === '5') {
      newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte5.default_price5 * this.p_Quantity;
      let prod5 = new Products(newProduct);
    } else if (this.addProductForm.controls.p_Product_type_id.value === '4') {
      newProduct.p_Subtotal = this.producte4.default_price4 * this.p_Quantity;
      let prod4 = new Products(newProduct);
    }
    this.product = newProduct;
    this.ps.addProduct(newProduct);
    this.router.navigate(['/invoice']);
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404321/calculate-value-using-angular check this

Comment: I can't understand. Can you suggest any solution please?

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: what you want to achieve is a simple calculation of totaling a purchase list containing multiple items with their default price, using angular, did I understand your problem correctly, am I right ?

Comment: @samartajShaikh Yes, I want to calculate only product that I chose. This code always counts on the default_price

Comment: @samartajShaikh have you any idea please?

Comment: @Chellappan thank you for your comment. In this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nqvxc?file=app/hello.component.ts you can see my problem. 1. Add product1, 2. Add product 2. 3. In table and console you can see that product 2 calculate quantity and default price product1

Comment: @Chellappan Please can you suggest me any idea how to solve my problem code?

Comment: Yes i wil try to solve wait bro

Comment: what do you mean by view what result are you expecting

Comment: I want to show real value, in there code, quantity * default price in last line

Comment: Any idea please?

Comment: currenltly its showing total properly in the example right

Comment: @Chellappan thank you so much, I solution this issue. Many thanx.  :)

Comment: add your code here it may benifit us